# Increase indentation of a paragraph

Tags: spacing, indentation, paragraphs, moderncv

I am using the `moderncv` package for making my resume however I am new to LaTeX, so please forgive me if this has been repeated (I did search) or is too stupid!

How do I increase the indent of a paragraph such that the *entire* paragraph is indented and not the first line only. In other words, try pasting a paragraph in `OpenOffice` and then choose `Increase indent`. Notice how the entire paragraph is indented.

I want this:

> Heading
>
> > a leo. Pellentesque sapien dui, facilisis et sollicitudin et, ullamcorper vel massa. Pellentesque vulputate placerat sapien, et volutpat odio elementum eget. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per

Where: `Heading` is a `section` and `a leo` is `cvitem`.

EDIT: As asked:

`\section{Foo} \cvitem{}{Para-Foo}`

Now I want `Para-Foo` to be indented as the way I have described...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. It would be very helpful to post a small example that we can copy and compile and then get on to fixing your problem rather than having to set it up ourselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `moderncv.cls` code it appears that `cvitem` uses the lengths `hintscolumnwidth` and `maincolumnwidth` to control the spacing on the left and the width of the text.  So, one way to do it would be to define a new command `\MyCvItem` which takes an optional first parameter allowing you to specify the indent amount. If the indent amount is not given, it defaults to 0.0pt.

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}

\firstname{Joey}
\familyname{TeXUser}

\newcommand*{\MyCvItem}[3][0.0pt]{%
    \addtolength{\hintscolumnwidth}{#1}% Adjust settings
    \addtolength{\maincolumnwidth}{-#1}%
    \cvitem{#2}{#3}%
    \addtolength{\hintscolumnwidth}{-#1}% Restore settings
    \addtolength{\maincolumnwidth}{#1}%
}%


\begin{document}\layout
\maketitle

\section{Heading}
\MyCvItem{a leo. }{% No indent specified
\textbf{Regular:} Pellentesque sapien dui, facilisis et sollicitudin et, ullamcorper vel massa. Pellentesque vulputate placerat sapien, et volutpat odio elementum eget. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
}

\textcolor{blue}{
\MyCvItem[1.0cm]{a leo. }{% Note optional indent amount specified
\textbf{Indented:} Pellentesque sapien dui, facilisis et sollicitudin et, ullamcorper vel massa. Pellentesque vulputate placerat sapien, et volutpat odio elementum eget. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
}}
\MyCvItem{a leo. }{% No indent specified -- ensure it is back to normal
\textbf{Regular:} Pellentesque sapien dui, facilisis et sollicitudin et, ullamcorper vel massa. Pellentesque vulputate placerat sapien, et volutpat odio elementum eget. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
}
\end{document}
```